# Redirect short-form URL to long-form URL (post_id to post_id + post_name)

Tags: permalinks, redirect, rewrite-rules

My blog uses this custom structure for permalinks:

> /%post_id%/%postname%/
>
> e.g.:
>   https://bilingueanglais.com/blog/1/combien-d-heures-faut-il-pour-apprendre-l-anglais/

Articles can then be accessed and linked to in two ways:

- Short form. e.g.: https://bilingueanglais.com/blog/1/
- Long form. e.g.: https://bilingueanglais.com/blog/1/combien-d-heures-faut-il-pour-apprendre-l-anglais/
- The canonical URL (set with `<link rel="canonical">`) is the long-form URL.

This is handy because, this way, links are shorter. Useful for sharing on Twitter.

What I'd like to do, is **create a redirect from the short-form URL to the long-form URL.**

My question is: where to do that?

As I understand it:

- `add_rewrite_rule` is not appropriate -- I cannot access `post_name` from it.
- `add_permastruct` is not appropriate either -- I cannot declare a redirection in it.

I guess I should create a hook somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think can do:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_func');
function my_func(){
    if(is_single()){
        // catch the last string
        preg_match('/(.*)\/(.*?)\//',  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $new_array);
        $last_phrase= $new_array[2];
        if(is_numeric($last_phrase)){
            $id = $last_phrase;
            header('location: '. get_permalink($id) , true, 301); exit;
        }
    }
}
```